# How to implement long press/swipe and delete on table rows - android titanium?

Tags: android, mobile, view, titanium, tableview

I having a tableView having some rows with labels. I want to delete row on long press/swipe on a particular row. I have added long press event for tableView but its callback method re the parameter as label which is in the tableViewRow.

how to get the selected index of the row???

```
table.addEventListener('longpress', function(e) {
            alert(e.source); //showing LabelProxy@2389hf

        });
```

Comment: You can use editable property of tableview only in iOS not in Android.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code for delete row on longClick.

```
var win = Ti.UI.currentWindow;
var data=[];
for (var x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
//var view = Ti.UI.createView();
var label = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text : 'Row Label ' + x,
    height : 'auto',
    width : 'auto',
    color : '#336699',
    left : 10
});
var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
    height : 50
});
row.add(label);
    data.push(row);
}

// create table view
var tableview = Titanium.UI.createTableView({
    data : data
});
tableview.addEventListener('longclick', function(e) {
    tableview.deleteRow(e.index);
});
win.add(tableview);
```

Comment: e.index is not the tableView index, it will returns the label object.. :(

Comment: Hi Udhaya, You can add your custom variable like **LabId** into your label and while you longclick on row you can get object of that lable like this way `alert(JSON.stringify(e.source.LabId));`

Comment: Also you can use     e.row.index for find which row is selected in tableview.

Comment: I just checked e.source, if it's label used e.source.parent.. fixed, thanks friends..